# Finding knot vector for Spline fitting

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, fitting

I have the following code from Mathematica:

```
pts = {{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 2}};

(*parameter to be fitted*)
a = 1;

(*Compute distances between control points*)
dist[a_] := 
  Accumulate[
   Table[EuclideanDistance[pts[[i]], pts[[i + 1]]]^
    a, {i, Length[pts] - 1}]];

(*Compute normalized parameters wrt the distances (chord length \
parametrization)*)
param[a_] := N[Prepend[dist[a]/Last[dist[a]], 0]];

(*degree of the B-spline*)
p = 3;

(*knots for interpolating B-spline*)
knots[a_] := 
  Join[ConstantArray[0, p + 1], 
   MovingAverage[ArrayPad[param[a], -1], p], ConstantArray[1, p + 1]];

(*Set up the square basis matrix to solve:*)
m[a_] := 
  Table[BSplineBasis[{3, knots[a]}, j - 1, param[a][[i]]], {i, 
    Length[pts]}, {j, Length[pts]}]; 

ctrlpts[a_] := LinearSolve[m[a], pts];

model[a_, t_] := 
  BSplineFunction[ctrlpts[a], SplineKnots -> knots[a], 
    SplineDegree -> p, SplineWeights -> Automatic][t];
```

The knot vector is given in this example. I would like to determine the knot vector itself by fitting.
I tried something like this, `FindFit[pts, model[a, t], {a}, t]`, which gives me errors.

I'm a Mathematica beginner, so please be patient.